# USB audio input is recording too slow, playing back too fast

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

There is a thread that explains how this happens, and what fixes it, but they did not show how they fixed it. Any information would be much appreciated.
 Here is the thread [USB Audio Input recording 3.3x too slow, playback 3.3x too fast, and garbled](https://askubuntu.com/questions/377526/usb-audio-input-recording-3-3x-too-slow-playback-3-3x-too-fast-and-garbled)

Comment: I highly advise you use an audio specific spin with jack / ardour 3 . Try Ubuntu studio. These spins are not just a bunch of default applications, but also kernel optimizations as well.  See http://ubuntustudio.org/ and http://libremusicproduction.com/articles/advantages-choosing-audio-orientated-linux-distribution . Audio specific spins resolved my usb audio issues.